# C# changing the source of an image box with uri

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I pretty much wrote a piece of code that picks which images to load in the imagebox based on a random int value.
I have all the images stored in a map called "projectImages" in my solution explorer. 
The error i'm getting is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll"
"Additional information: Invalid URI". Which probably means i'm not connecting the link properly.

Thanks in advance.

```
    {
       int[] ImageValues = new int[15];
       ImageValues[0] = 1;
       ImageValues[1] = 2;
       ImageValues[2] = 3;
       ImageValues[3] = 4;
       ImageValues[4] = 5;
       ImageValues[5] = 6;
       ImageValues[6] = 7;
       ImageValues[7] = 8;
       ImageValues[8] = 9;
       ImageValues[9] = 10;
       ImageValues[10] = 11;
       ImageValues[11] = 12;
       ImageValues[12] = 13;
       ImageValues[13] = 14;
       ImageValues[14] = 15;

       Random randomize = new Random();
       int initialValue = randomize.Next(1, 16);
       int finalValue = ImageValues[initialValue];

       if(finalValue == 1)
       {
           leftImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\triangle.png"));
           midImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\circle.png"));
           rightImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\square.png"));
           question.Content = "Kan jij de driehoek aanwijzen?";
       }

       else if(finalValue == 2)
       {
           leftImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\middelstestaaf.png"));
           midImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\kortestaaf.png"));
           rightImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\langestaaf.png"));
           question.Content = "Kan jij de langste staaf aanwijzen?";
       }

       else if (finalValue == 3)
       {
           leftImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\triangle.png"));
           midImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\circle.png"));
           rightImagebox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"projectImages\square.png");
           question.Content = "Kan jij de cirkel aanwijzen?";
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you make sure that you've already reference the image resource in your project and the path is correct, if so, try
`new Uri(@"YourPath", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)`.

And if you use WPF or Silverlight, I strongly recommend you use Pack Uri in your project, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) is the official document about pack uri.

Then the Uri should look like this:

`new Uri(@"ms-appx:///,,,:YourPath/projectImages/triangle.png")`